# Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I get this error when trying to checkout with stripe:

> Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client secret of the form ${id}*secret*${secret}. You specified: .....

I use stripe on my website and I've implemented it with firebase functions. When I run my website and firebase functions locally I do not get this error, but when I have it on my firebase hosting it does not work and I get that error. Locally I would run these commands: `npm start` to start the website and then I cd inside the functions folder and then run `npm run serve`. How can I fix this?
Here is the index.js file that is being run with firebase functions:
**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const stripe = require('stripe')(secret_key)
const app = express();
app.use(cors({
    origin: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/payments/create', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { amount, shipping } = req.body;
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            shipping,
            amount,
            currency: 'eur'
        });

        res
        .status(200)
        .send(paymentIntent.client_secret);
    }catch(err) {
        res
        .status(500)
        .json({
            statusCode: 500,
            message: err.message
        });
    }
})

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res
    .status(404)
    .send('404, Not Found');
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Here's the **package.json**

```
  {
"name": "evelinas-art-store",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
  "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
  "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
  "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "ckeditor4-react": "^1.3.0",
  "firebase": "^8.2.1",
  "moment": "^2.29.1",
  "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-country-region-selector": "^3.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
  "redux": "^4.0.5",
  "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
  "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
  "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
  "reselect": "^4.0.0",
  "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ]
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
 }
}
```

File that has stripe payment

````
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
  import FormInput from './../forms/FormInput';
  import Button from './../forms/Button';
  import { CountryDropdown } from 'react-country-region-selector';
  import { apiInstance } from './../../Utils';
  import { selectCartTotal, selectCartItemsCount, selectCartItems } from './../../redux/Cart/cart.selectors';
  import { saveOrderHistory } from './../../redux/Orders/orders.actions';
  import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
  import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
  import './styles.scss';

  const initialAddressState = {
    line1: '',
    line2: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    postal_code: '',
    country: '',
  };

  const mapState = createStructuredSelector({
    total: selectCartTotal,
    itemCount: selectCartItemsCount,
    cartItems: selectCartItems,
  });

  const PaymentDetails = () => {
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const history = useHistory();
    const { total, itemCount, cartItems } = useSelector(mapState);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [billingAddress, setBillingAddress] = useState({ ...initialAddressState });
    const [shippingAddress, setShippingAddress] = useState({ ...initialAddressState });
    const [recipientName, setRecipientName] = useState('');
     const [nameOnCard, setNameOnCard] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
      if (itemCount < 1) {
        history.push('/dashboard');
      }

    }, [itemCount]);

    const handleShipping = evt => {
      const { name, value } = evt.target;
      setShippingAddress({
        ...shippingAddress,
        [name]: value
      });
    };

    const handleBilling = evt => {
      const { name, value } = evt.target;
      setBillingAddress({
        ...billingAddress,
        [name]: value
      });
    }

    const handleFormSubmit = async evt => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      const cardElement = elements.getElement('card');

      if (
        !shippingAddress.line1 || !shippingAddress.city ||
        !shippingAddress.state || !shippingAddress.postal_code ||
        !shippingAddress.country || !billingAddress.line1 ||
        !billingAddress.city || !billingAddress.state ||
        !billingAddress.postal_code || !billingAddress.country ||
        !recipientName || !nameOnCard
      ) {
        return;
      }

      apiInstance.post('/payments/create', {
        amount: total * 100,
        shipping: {
          name: recipientName,
          address: {
            ...shippingAddress
          }
        }
      }).then(({ data: clientSecret }) => {

        stripe.createPaymentMethod({
          type: 'card',
          card: cardElement,
          billing_details: {
            name: nameOnCard,
            address: {
              ...billingAddress
            }
          }
        }).then(({ paymentMethod }) => {

          stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: paymentMethod.id
          })
          .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {

            const configOrder = {
              orderTotal: total,
              orderItems: cartItems.map(item => {
                const { documentID, productThumbnail, productName,
                  productPrice, quantity } = item;

                return {
                  documentID,
                  productThumbnail,
                  productName,
                  productPrice,
                  quantity
                };
              })
            }

            dispatch(
              saveOrderHistory(configOrder)
            );
          });

        })


      });

    };

    const configCardElement = {
      iconStyle: 'solid',
      style: {
        base: {
          fontSize: '16px'
        }
      },
      hidePostalCode: true
    };

    return (
      <div className="paymentDetails">
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>

          <div className="group">
            <h2>
              Shipping Address
            </h2>

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="Recipient Name"
              name="recipientName"
              handleChange={evt => setRecipientName(evt.target.value)}
              value={recipientName}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="Line 1"
              name="line1"
              handleChange={evt => handleShipping(evt)}
              value={shippingAddress.line1}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              placeholder="Line 2"
              name="line2"
              handleChange={evt => handleShipping(evt)}
              value={shippingAddress.line2}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="City"
              name="city"
              handleChange={evt => handleShipping(evt)}
              value={shippingAddress.city}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="State"
              name="state"
              handleChange={evt => handleShipping(evt)}
              value={shippingAddress.state}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="Postal Code"
              name="postal_code"
              handleChange={evt => handleShipping(evt)}
              value={shippingAddress.postal_code}
              type="text"
            />

            <div className="formRow checkoutInput">
              <CountryDropdown
                required
                onChange={val => handleShipping({
                  target: {
                    name: 'country',
                    value: val
                  }
                })}
                value={shippingAddress.country}
                valueType="short"
              />
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className="group">
            <h2>
              Billing Address
            </h2>

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="Name on Card"
              name="nameOnCard"
              handleChange={evt => setNameOnCard(evt.target.value)}
              value={nameOnCard}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="Line 1"
              name="line1"
              handleChange={evt => handleBilling(evt)}
              value={billingAddress.line1}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              placeholder="Line 2"
              name="line2"
              handleChange={evt => handleBilling(evt)}
              value={billingAddress.line2}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="City"
              name="city"
              handleChange={evt => handleBilling(evt)}
              value={billingAddress.city}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="State"
              name="state"
              handleChange={evt => handleBilling(evt)}
              value={billingAddress.state}
              type="text"
            />

            <FormInput
              required
              placeholder="Postal Code"
              name="postal_code"
              handleChange={evt => handleBilling(evt)}
              value={billingAddress.postal_code}
              type="text"
            />

            <div className="formRow checkoutInput">
              <CountryDropdown
                required
                onChange={val => handleBilling({
                  target: {
                    name: 'country',
                    value: val
                  }
                })}
                value={billingAddress.country}
                valueType="short"
              />
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className="group">
            <h2>
              Card Details
            </h2>

            <CardElement
              options={configCardElement}
            />
          </div>

          <Button
            type="submit"
          >
            Pay Now
          </Button>

        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default PaymentDetails;```
````

Comment: show the code for how `secret_key` is set. that is likely your issue

Comment: updated the post with the new file, these files are the only ones that use anything related to stripe

Comment: why didn't you answer my question. where does this value `secret_key` come from? its not shown in your server code, and that is what the error is all about.

Comment: first file 4th line with the require ('stripe')

Comment: i can see you use the variable there, but it is not defined anywhere. so where does this variable come from? can you try `console.log(secret_key)` and show the output (if it contain sensitive data, you can just put <SENSITIVE> or something

Comment: The full error message should contain the information you need to fix this issue. Could you share the last part of the error message (i.e., "You specified: .....")?. Do you see a payment intent client secret or something else? This likely doesn't have anything to do with your secret key as you'd be getting a different error otherwise.

Comment: @r3wt when I log I get the secret key.

Comment: @ttmarek the .... represent the secret key which I would not like to type it here. So after You specified: comes the secret key

Comment: I still don't know how it works locally but not when I use it with my domain.

Comment: Hm, are you sure @AnastasisPap? A secret key will have the form `sk_test_xxxx` or `sk_live_xxxxx`. Is that what you're seeing? Your server-side code doesn't suggest that that would be possible.

Comment: If I try to console it yes it returns sk_live_....... Maybe I haven't configured properly something in firebase functions? Because why should it run locally and not when hosted?

Comment: What would you suggest to do? Like what should I rewrite

Comment: @AnastasisPap. its flat out impossible for us to help you as you aren't providing us with enough information unfortunately. you need to go wherever `secret_key` variable is defined(since you didn't require the var, i'm assuming its stored somewhere as a global) and you need to tell us how that value is defined (is it just a constant string or is it being read from `process.env.<SOME VAR NAME>` (its probably an env variable or something). my hunch is that the env variable is missing in prod and needs to be set.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create
for stripe.PaymentIntent.create()

You need to pass this:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_51I5EU6DbwDQYqmKoHRVYU2jw4jtzB8aQa6byuVIMyfDvYl3lxHOzmIRUZ6SabMmk1TV0jNu4w9akIgPY4E3krUbj00ewcroCvC"

  const PaymentIntentVar =  stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
  amount=2000,
  currency="usd",
  payment_method_types=["card"],
)
```

You have a typo , I guess ? PaymentIntents ?
After please try to :

```
console.log(PaymentIntentVar)
```

in index.js
To see if you are getting the correct response ? Would you please share that !

Also in " File that has stripe payment" :

instead of :

```
const cardElement = elements.getElement('card');
```

and this:

```
stripe.createPaymentMethod({
          type: 'card',
          card: cardElement,
          billing_details: {
            name: nameOnCard,
            address: {
              ...billingAddress
            }
          }
        })
```

do this :

```
stripe.createPaymentMethod({
          type: 'card',
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
          billing_details: {
            name: nameOnCard,
            address: {
              ...billingAddress
            }
          }
        })
```

also check you are passing the correct public and secret keys on your front and backend by console.log() on front and backend

Also instead useStripe, try this

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripe = loadStripe('secret_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible scenarios and how I understand the configuration.

1. pass
2. requires 3d secure
3. fail - insufficient funds

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#additional-testing-resources

So first you attempt a payment from the front end

```
      const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: 'card',
        card: cardElement,
        billing_details: {
          name: `${stateProps.userProfile.firstName} ${stateProps.userProfile.lastName}`,
          email: stateProps.user.email
        }
      });
```

from that paymentMethod, you retrieve paymentMethod.Id and send that to your server to make a payment - at this point we are assuming the payment will work and not require 3d secure.

In my case, I need is that paymentMethod.Id because I have put all the billing details in a different object.

In the backend, here is what I have using C#

```
    try
    {
        if (request.PaymentMethodId != null)
        {
            var createOptions = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
            {
                PaymentMethod = request.PaymentMethodId,
                Amount = request.total,
                Currency = "gbp",
                ConfirmationMethod = "manual",
                Confirm = true,
                //ReturnUrl = "",
                Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "OrderId", request.orderId.ToString() },
                }
            };

            paymentIntent = paymentIntentService.Create(createOptions);
        }

        if (request.PaymentIntentId != null)
        {
            var confirmOptions = new PaymentIntentConfirmOptions { };
            paymentIntent = paymentIntentService.Confirm(
                request.PaymentIntentId,
                confirmOptions
            );
        }
    }
    catch (StripeException e)
    {
        return new ViewModels.ResponseObject
        {
            Success = false,
            Title = "An Error Occcured.",
            Message = e.Message,
            Data = e.Message
        };
    }

    if (paymentIntent.Status == "requires_action" && paymentIntent.NextAction.Type == "use_stripe_sdk")
    {
        return new ViewModels.ResponseObject
        {
            Success = false,
            Data = new
            {
                requires_action = true,
                payment_intent_client_secret = paymentIntent.ClientSecret
            },
            Title = "Requires Action",
            Message = "Requires Action"
        };
    }
    else if (paymentIntent.Status == "succeeded")
    {
        return new ViewModels.ResponseObject
        {
            Success = true,
            Title = "Payment Successful.",
            Message = "Thank you. Your payment has been successful. A confirmation message has been sent to you by email.",
            Data = null
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return new ViewModels.ResponseObject
        {
            Success = false,
            Title = "An Error Occcured.",
            Message = "An error has occured with your payment. A representative from our store has been notified and will be in touch with you to resolve the issue.",
            Data = null
        };
    }
```

So if you read the code, you will see that it tries to make a payment and if that fails, THEN it gives you the clientSecret and you can return that to the client.

This is what you can now use on the front end to construct a payment intent (which we already know will fail due to 3d secure) that will automatically pull up the 3d secure authentication window.

In my opinion it seems a waste to do the roundtrip twice but that's how I managed to beat it into submission.

Answer (score 0):

This Happens when your element options are not correctly configured.

I am using vue stripe framework and I had the same bug when I was developing this.

vue component setup

```html
<StripeElementPayment
    ref="checkoutRef"
    :pk="stripeConfig._apiKey"
    mode="payment"
    :test-mode="true"
    :elements-options="elementsOptions"
    :confirm-params="confirmParams"
    :locale="stripeConfig._locale"
    :stripe-account="stripeConfig._stripeAccount"
/>
```

// element options, last three elements are not madotary for testing

```
elementsOptions: any = {
    appearance: {}, // appearance options
    mode: 'payment',
    currency: 'aud',
    amount: this.totalAmount
}
```